# Do I need to use commit if I am only getting values

Tags: scalardb

I want to check if a user exists in the the database or not. Do I need to use `commit`? Is this code the right way to go about getting values?

```
val transaction: DistributedTransaction = transactionService.start
    logger.trace("transaction started: " + transaction);
    //Perform the operations you want to group in the transaction

    val pUserKey = new Key(new IntValue("bucket", utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(userKeys.bucket)),
      new TextValue("email", userKeys.email)
    )
    val cUserKey = new Key(
      new TextValue("authprovider", "credentials"),
      new TextValue("firstname", userKeys.firstName),
      new TextValue("lastname", userKeys.lastName)
    )
    logger.trace("created keys. ")
    logger.trace("getting user")
    val get:Get = new Get(pUserKey,cUserKey);

    val result:Optional[Result] = transaction.get(get);
    if(result.isPresent){
      logger.trace(s"found user ${result}")
    } else {
      logger.trace(s"user doesn't exist")
    }

    try {
      logger.trace(s"committing")
      transaction.commit()
    } catch {
      case e1:UnknownTransactionStatusException =>{
        logger.error("error in commiting. Unknowns status")
        throw e1;

      }
      case e2:CommitException =>{
        logger.error("error in commiting. Rolling back")
        transaction.abort();
        throw e2;
      }
    }
```

When will the values actually be fetched? When I call `transaction.get` or when I call `transaction.commit`?

Comment: You should describe what the questions are about. Having `scalardb` tag is not clear enough if the questions are about Scalar DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please always call `commit` in Scalar DB.

It isn't actually needed for the default SNAPSHOT but it is needed for SERIALIZABLE so it's a good practice to call it always.